# How do I rearrange $s=vt+v(\frac{m}{b})(e^{-(\frac{b}{m}t)}-1)$ to make $t$ the function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've tried Wolfram Alpha for this, but the result contains a W([expression]), which I don't understand. Even just knowing what that means would probably be enough to get the answer I need, honestly.

As a side-note, I don't really know what else to tag this question with, or even if this is the right tag, so feel free to suggest tag amendments.

Comment: Lambert's [W function](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Lambert_W) is the inverse to the *product exponential* function $P(w) = w \, e^w$. In other words, $w = W(x)$ if and only if $x = w \, e^w$ on an appropriate restricted domain. The *principal branch* $W_0$ (restricted to the real numbers) is the inverse of $P(w)$ for $w \geq -1$, so $W$ is defined for $x \geq -e^{-1}$. Look at [the graphs](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fy905e0bq0).

Comment: @SammyBlack I did some research on the Lambert W function, and I think I understand it. Using [this Wolfram Alpha widget](https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=3d613c498715c870be91ed38004abc81), I got $t=(\frac{MvW_n(-e^{-\frac{bs}{Mv}-1})+bs+Mv}{bv})$ (assuming that I read the formatting correctly). Would the $W_n()$ be the Lambert W function in this case?

Answer (score 4):

*Just to show you how it works*

Rearrange the expression using $t=-\frac m b x$ and simplify as much as you can to obtain by the end
$$e^x=x+a \qquad \text{where} \qquad a=1+\frac{b s}{m v}$$ Now, make $x+a=y$ to get
$$e^y =b y \qquad \text{where} \qquad b=e^a$$ and now the solution is
$$y=-W\left(-\frac{1}{b}\right)$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function.

If I may suggest, it is worth to look at this function. Even if non-elementary, it is simple and has a lot of applications. To give you an idea, on the search bar, type *Lambert* : $3924$ entries !